# Running service automatically enters oncreate

Tags: android, batterylevel

Below given code is written to track battery level of device and store it in db. In order to get battery level, function "batterylevel" is called every 3 minutes, and battery level is inserted to db table. And also code saves the time, when device gets full charged, in another db table. Everything works fine for some time. But problem occurs after about 30 minutes, the running service automatically enters to its oncreate method, after that service won't show any logs, eventually service stops causing force close while trying to stop the service manually.

```
public class BatteryLevelService extends Service {
    BroadcastReceiver batteryLevelReceiver;
    Timer t ;
    Calendar cal;
    Date lastBatteryFullTime;
    Context context;
    int sec;
    int lastFullChargeYear,lastFullChargeMonth,lastFullChargeDay;
    int lastFullChargeHour,lastFullChargeMinute,lastFullChargeSecond;
    private File dir;


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
@Override
public void onCreate(){

    Log.d("Service", "oncreate Service Started");

}

    private void batteryLevel() {
    cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    long currentHour=cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    long currentMinute=cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    long currentSecond=cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    final String currentTime=currentHour+" : "+currentMinute+" : "+currentSecond;

    Intent batteryIntent = registerReceiver(null,
            new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    int rawlevel = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
    int scale = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
    int level = -1;
    if (rawlevel >= 0 && scale > 0) {
        level = (rawlevel * 100) / scale;

    }
    MainActivity.sqladp.insertBatteryLevel(level, currentTime);
    if(level==100){
        cal=cal.getInstance();
        lastFullChargeYear=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        lastFullChargeMonth=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        lastFullChargeDay=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        lastFullChargeHour=cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        lastFullChargeMinute=cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        lastFullChargeSecond=cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        lastBatteryFullTime=new Date(lastFullChargeYear, lastFullChargeMonth, lastFullChargeDay, lastFullChargeHour, lastFullChargeMinute);

        String[] lastFullChargeTime=lastBatteryFullTime.toString().split("GMT");
        MainActivity.sqladp.deleteLastFullBattery();
        MainActivity.sqladp.insertLastUsage("Battery", "", lastFullChargeTime[0], "");
    }
    Log.d("Battery level", ""+level + "%");
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {


    Log.d("Service", "Service Started");
    t = new Timer();
    //Set the schedule function and rate
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Called each time when 1000 milliseconds (1 second) (the period parameter)
            batteryLevel();
            Log.d("", "batlevel ");
        }

    },
    //Set how long before to start calling the TimerTask (in milliseconds)
    0,
    //Set the amount of time between each execution (in milliseconds)
    3*60*1000);


}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    Log.d("service", "onDestroy");
    t.cancel();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method onStart() is only used for old Android versions (<2.0). For later versions you should use onStartCommand() as bellow:

```
@Override
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
```

this will solve your problem